# operator is unused Swift

Tags: swift

I have a UIbutton inside a function and I'm calling to hide it if a textfield is empty. but I keep getting this warning that operator '==' is unused. How can I resolve this.

```
if textfield == ""{
 button.isHidden == true -> this is where I get the warning

}
```

Comment: Also, it is better to use `isEmpty` rather than `== ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the assignment instead of the equality operator.

```
button.isHidden = true
```

If you are trying to determine whether or not the button is hidden, than you would use the `==` equality operator in conjunction with an `if` statement.

Also as Fahim pointed out in the comment, your if statement is checking if the textField is not `nil`, but what you probably want is to check if the text field is blank. So you should check the `.text` property:

```
if textField.text == "" {
    button.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: @john Also, in the above code, you might be checking the text field and not the text of the field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wanna write something like this ? `if textField.text == "" {
     button.isHidden = true
}`